# Query SQL group by per next row if have same value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

How to do group by if the value of the next column is the same, later I will calculate how long the purchase will take, later added per group

[image]

Comment: I reverted you last edit so that the answer makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a classic Gaps-and-Islands Problem.

In the future, please provide sample data as TEXT not as an image.

**Example**

```
with cte as (
    Select *
          ,Grp = row_number() over (order by ID) 
                -row_number() over (partition by BUAH order by ID)
    From  YourTable
)
Select BUAH
      ,Cnt = sum(1)
 From cte
 Group By BUAH,Grp
 Order By min(ID)   --<< Optional
```

**Results**

```
BUAH    Cnt
APEL    2
TOMAT   2
APEL    3
...
```

Comment: sorry jhon i just edited the data with real case can you help me?

Comment: @RamaDhani you can't go changing your question such that it's totally different to you original post when people have already answered. You should revert your changes, accept this answer and ask a new question. And then avoid wasting peoples time in future!

Comment: `sum(1)` ?? why not just `COUNT(*)`?

Comment: @Charlieface because there is no difference other than I save two whole keystrokes :)  https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2021/06/25/sql-server-sum1-vs-count-performance-observation/#:~:text=Lots%20of%20people%20find%20it,Both%20are%20equal.

Comment: Each to their own, I would take the more explicit syntax https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-wrong-optimizations#opt6

Answer (score -2):

User `COUNT` with `GROUP BY` to achieve it.

```
SELECT BUAH, COUNT(*) AS Total FROM your_table GROUP BY `WAKTU BELI`
```

Comment: its will be
APEL 5
TOMAT 3
MELON 2

Comment: my bad, i have edited it, it should be group by WAKTU BELI

Comment: To even pass a syntax check you'd need at least square brackets `[WAKTU BELI]`. But it doesn't come close to providing the desired results.

Comment: i'm sorry, i will take notes about the square bracket, but how is it not answering the question @Dale K?

Comment: Compare your answer to the other answer. There are gaps and islands.